# Get Days names between two dates (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the names of days between 2 dates ?
For example:
Let startDate=2021-08-09
Let endDate=2021-08-18

I want this result:
Mon,Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon,Tue

Is it possible ?

Comment: it is possible - what have you tried?

Comment: I'm still searching for some answers

Comment: Whereabouts in solving this problem did you get stuck? Have you broken it down into steps as yet, did you make a start with any code?

Comment: Not yet,I'm still searching for codes :/

Comment: Come on, don't search for code, write your own, you are a programmer. It's not that complex problem at all. Here is the code you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: lol, u know programmer need help from time to time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var from = new Date(2014, 3, 11);
var to = new Date(2014, 3, 13);
var DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var d = from;
while (d <= to) {
    alert(DAYS[d.getDay()]);
    d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding 24h, consider `setUTCDate` to `getUTCDate + 1`

Comment: @PaulS. can u explain more ?because I'm getting wrong days number with getDay().Where should I put getUTCDate ?

Comment: @Slimen What is the input on which you receive wrong numbers?

Comment: @eugene82 for example if I use these dates (11/04/2014-->15/04/2014) I should get this result with getDay() (5,6,0,1,2)but this is what I get (0,1,2,3,4) !!!

Comment: Date constructor accepts 0-based months. So, use 03 instead of 04.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)` than add `24` hours to avoid issues when crossing *DST* boundaries.

```
function days(from, to) {
    var d = new Date(from),
        a = [],
        y = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    while (d < to) {
        a.push(y[d.getDay()]);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }
    if (d.getDay() === to.getDay()) // include last day
        a.push(y[d.getDay()]);
    return a;
}

// ex. usage
var from = new Date(2014, 4 - 1, 11),
    to = new Date(2014, 4 - 1, 13);
days(from, to); // ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

Comment: why u did 4-1 ?? and if it's the first month 1-1 = 0 !!

Comment: @Slimen `0` is the first month in _JavaScript's Date_.

Comment: I did this modification :if(MONTH == 0){
      MONTH = 12;
      YEAR = parseInt(YEAR)-1;
   },and I get the right days !

Comment: @Slimen `+new Date(2013, 12, 1) === +new Date (2014, 0, 1); //true` (i.e. both are _January 1st, 2014_)